# How to select the time difference between rows and filter

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `MySQL 5.7` to calculate the time difference in seconds between successive rows.  I have a few questions

1. How does this select the previous row to use for each resulting rows calculation? Specifically, what part of the query is actually doing this?
2. How can I filter the `@diff` column to exclude `0` or values larger than, say, `60` seconds? Any time I try to add a `WHERE` clause, i get an error.
3. Once filtered, should I then be able to `SUM` the `@diff` column to get total time?

### Query

```
SELECT @diff   AS start,
       created AS end,
       IF(@diff = 0, 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`created`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@diff)) AS diff,
       @diff := created AS endtime
FROM   events,
       (SELECT @diff := 0) AS x
ORDER  BY events.created
```

### Source Table `events`

```
Desc      | Timestamp
-------------------------------
Event 1   | 2019-01-03 17:21:03
Event 2   | 2019-01-03 17:21:03
Event 3   | 2019-01-03 17:21:03
Event 4   | 2019-01-03 17:21:14
Event 5   | 2019-01-03 17:21:16
Event 6   | 2019-01-03 17:25:46
```

### Current Result

```
start               | end                   | diff      | endtime
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
0                   | 2019-01-03 17:21:03   | 0         | 2019-01-03 17:21:03
2019-01-03 17:21:03 | 2019-01-03 17:21:03   | 0.000000  | 2019-01-03 17:21:03
2019-01-03 17:21:03 | 2019-01-03 17:21:03   | 0.000000  | 2019-01-03 17:21:03
2019-01-03 17:21:03 | 2019-01-03 17:21:14   | 11.00000  | 2019-01-03 17:21:14
2019-01-03 17:21:14 | 2019-01-03 17:21:16   | 2.000000  | 2019-01-03 17:21:16
2019-01-03 17:21:16 | 2019-01-03 17:25:46   | 270.0000  | 2019-01-03 17:25:46
```

### Desired Result

```
start               | end                   | diff      | endtime
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-03 17:21:03 | 2019-01-03 17:21:14   | 11.00000  | 2019-01-03 17:21:14
2019-01-03 17:21:14 | 2019-01-03 17:21:16   | 2.000000  | 2019-01-03 17:21:16
```

Comment: I would suggest that you ask another question about getting the results you need.  Your query is flawed, because `@diff` is assigned in one expression, but used in two others.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff That question has been ask many times. This is the solution I settled on and it works, minus my ability to filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you should use window functions:

```
SELECT lag(created) over (order by created)   AS start,
       created AS end,
       coalesce(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lag(created) over (order by created)), 0) as diff
FROM events e
ORDER BY e.created;
```

In earlier versions your code is poorly written, because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.

Comment: Any recommendation for MySQL 5.7?